# Wagtail Create Snippet from the frontend to accepts Images (Django)

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I have a simple snippet using Django Wagtail. I would like to be able to update the logo from a "CreateView" but when it renders in my view it's expecting a foreign key. I would imagine it would be easy to create a from to do this but it's not.

```
@register_snippet
class MerchantSnippet(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    logo = models.ForeignKey(
                    'wagtailimages.Image',
                    null=True,
                    blank=True,
                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    panels =[
        FieldPanel('name'),
        ImageChooserPanel('logo'),
   ]

   edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
       ObjectList(panels, heading='Content'),
       ])



class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ProductSnippet
    fields = ['name','logo']

 class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = ProductSnippet
    fields = ['name','logo']
```

When I use the default example in the template I ended up just getting a drop down.

```
 {% render_field field class+="form-control" %}
```

How would I be able to see an image preview in the event I am updating the snippet and the ability to upload a different one . In the event I am creating a new item the ability to select an upload an image.

Answer (score 1):

The `logo` field is a foreign key and points to Wagtail Image. Therefore it is a select. If you change the `logo` field to a [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) you probably have the behaviour you desire. However, uploaded logos will *not* appear in the Wagtail Images. That ain't a bad thing. Whenever you want to display a logo, you'd just use the ​Merchant snippet.

If storing the logo as a Wagtail Image is a must, there are two alternatives:

**Alternative 1: Custom form**

`CreateView` and `UpdateView` are Django generic views and inherit the [FormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin). This means you can specify a custom `form_class`. Create a custom form with a `logo = ImageField(...)` and on submit, handle the image data, create a Wagtail Image, and store the Wagtail Image pk on the snippet.

**Alternative 2: Multiple forms**

Django can handle [multiple forms inside a single form tag with a prefix to avoid field name collisions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-form). So you can present both the snippet and the Wagtail image within the same view.

Note: `@register_snippet` is needed for Wagtail to display CRUD views and enable the snippet chooser in the Wagtail admin interface. But a snippet is a regular Django model. Wagtail Image is a regular Django model too. Forms and generic views are also pure Django concepts. If you dive into this some more, leave Wagtail out of your search queries.